# Complete Android Eclipse Development Package

Tags: android, eclipse

There are complete downloadable packages for developing php, java, etc with Eclipse, but has anyone put together an Android specific package?

I realize it's not that hard to get it up and running, but would be nice to just download and unpack "Eclipse: Android" and be up and running with the latest SDKs, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to break it to you but I don't think anyone has bothered to wrap up everything into a bundle. I think part of the problem is that the Android SDK changes every damn month or something so it might be a bit obnoxious to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

Motodev studio combines all the elements needed for android development into a single, regularly updated package.

http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/

Answer (score 2):

This is old question, but there actually is exactly what is the OP looking for.

Just download the [ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)